# Longtable and tikz

Tags: longtable, bidi

I used a preamble for many months where tikz and longtable lived together without problems. From a few days, I think after last update, I have the problem that I have reproduced with the MWE I send. 
If you activate the three lines commented, a strange error appear, related to a missing brace.
I would like to know if and what mistake I made.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openany,10pt,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{tikz} %%%
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes} %%%
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,decorations.text,positioning,decorations.markings} %%%
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin {document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable} {c   
                        p{.8\textwidth}  
                        c
                        c
                        }\\
\caption{Indice delle copie dei documenti originali}\\

\toprule
doc. & titolo & pag. & pagg. \\%
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{{\itshape \tablename\ \thetable{} -- segue dalla pagina precedente}} \\

\hline 
doc. & titolo & pag. & pagg. \\%
\hline 
\endhead

\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\emph{continua alla pagina seguente}}\\%
\endfoot

\endlastfoot

H1 & Descrizione & pag. h1 & 66\\%
H2 & Descrizione & pag. h2 & 4 \\%
H3-1 & Descrizione & pag. h3 & 26 \\%
H3-2 & Descrizione & pag. h3 & 8 \\%
H4 & Descrizione & pag. h4 & 21 \\%
H5 & Descrizione & pag. h5 & 11 \\%
H6 & Descrizione & pag. h6 & 12 \\%
H7 & Descrizione & pag. h7 & 8 \\%
H8 & Descrizione & pag. h8 & 16 \\%
H9-1 & Descrizione & pag. h9 & 14 \\%
H9-2 & Descrizione & pag. h9 & 7 \\%
H10 & Descrizione & pag. h10 & 9\\%
H11 & Descrizione & pag. h11 & 30 \\%
H12 & Descrizione & H12 & \\%
H13 & Descrizione  & H13 & \\%
H14 & Descrizione  & H14 & \\%
H15 & Descrizione  & H15 & \\%
H16 & Descrizione  & H16 & \\%
H17 & Descrizione  & H17 & \\%
H18 & Descrizione  & H18 & \\%
H19 & Descrizione  & H19 & \\%
H20 & Descrizione  & H20 & \\%
H21 & Descrizione  & H21 & \\%
H22 & Descrizione  & H22 & \\%
H23 & Descrizione  & H23 & \\%
H24 & Descrizione  & H24 & \\%
H25 & Descrizione & H25 & 17 \\% 

\hline 
 & & & 232 \\%

\hline 

\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

longtable has changed. When a color package is loaded (as it does when you use tikz) then it inserts an additional `\color@begingroup`. But the bidi code doesn't contain yet the needed correction. Until bidi is corrected you can try this patch:

```
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
 %after bidi is loaded!
\makeatletter 
\patchcmd\LT@startpbox{\bgroup}{\bgroup\color@begingroup}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
```